# Ubuntu 12.04 Cannot update kernels

Tags: grub2, kernel

Currently I cannot load the kernel 3.8.0-39-generic, or 3.8.0-38-generic. I have to go back and use 37, is there anywhere I can remove the two newer ones and re install them?

Answer (score 0):

To see all your installed kernels you can open Synaptic and do a search for "linux".  Sort by "installed" to make it easy on yourself, then carefully remove all the packages for whichever kernel versions you want.  This is usually how I do it when I want to clean up my installed kernels.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer GUI applications you can install [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) which includes a system janitor section. From there you can manage -among other things - the installed kernels.